# How do I trigger successive CSS transforms with transitions using jQuery's .css()?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, translate

Here's a breakdown of what I'm trying to achieve.

1. Translate the Y position of a box using CSS transform **without** a transition. e.g. translate Y - 200px.
2. Translate the box back to the original position with a transition. e.g. translate Y - 0px.

Seems like the last translation is cancelling the first translation. I'm just not entirely sure how to chain this correctly.

See my attempt below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.box', function() {
    $( this ).css( 'transform', 'translate(0px, 200px)' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'animating' );
    $( this ).css( 'transform', 'translate(0px, 0px)' );
  } );
} );
```

```css
.box {
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: #0f0;
}

.box.animating {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you. Use `show()` to add a small timeout between two anoimations

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.box', function() {
    $( this ).css( 'transform', 'translate(0px, 200px)' ).show().addClass( 'animating' ).css( 'transform', 'translate(0px, 0px)' );
  } );
} );
```

```css
.box {
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: #0f0;
}

.box.animating {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find your solution here [Click Me](https://jsfiddle.net/5x5xujdL/)

Just change in css:

```
.box {
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: #0f0;
}

.box:hover {
   width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I hope this will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeOut on the second css transformation like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.box', function() {
     $( '.box').css( 'transform', 'translate(0px, 200px)' ); 
     setTimeout(function(){
        $( '.box' ).addClass( 'animating' );
        $( '.box' ).css( 'transform', 'translate(0px, 0px)' );
     }, 200);
   
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: #0f0;
}

.box.animating {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
            bottom: "200px"
             }, 100, function() {
             $(this).addClass( 'animating' );
             $(this).animate({
               top:"0px"
             },2000);
          });
  } );
```

```css
.box {
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: #0f0;
  position:absolute;
}

.box.animating {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

I have used jquery animate to perform the required animation